# Zoom capability in Catalog (not in product Page)

Tags: jquery, magento

I'm on Magento 1.6.2.
I want to have a zooming capability in the catalog page.
When the customer hovers over a product image this should show a bigger picture like this http://demo.superdit.com/jquery/zoom_hover/.
Note that I don’t want this in the product page, only in catalog.

I have fancybox and Jquery is this possible with these libraries?
I dont want to use another extension if this is possible with the mentioned libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the CSS :hover selector changing the dimensions of the image to make it bigger and positioned it with an offset so that it looks like zooming.

Here is the code:

```
:hover{
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: -55px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 330px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fancybox doesn't give you this functionality however I've integrated both fancybox and magiczoom plus and had no issues at all. Been running in production for a while.

Need any pointers give me a shout.

Comment: Thank for your reply. I would definitely go with the no extra extension solution if its possible.

Comment: You changed example from magiczoom as I'd mentioned in my answer. To achieve that result you could use an image switch and use animate functionality in jQuery.

Comment: Do you have an example code on how this can be implemented? It's just magento is a bit complicated so I don't know where the images should be store or the naming pattern that I should follow so that every image has its matching one(the one with the better quality).